# Quotations Must Match When they Do?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, visual-studio-2015

I have an ASP.NET MVC app with the following line in the markup:

```
<i class=' fa fa-circle-thin fa-stack-2x'></i>
```

When I build this application, I get the following warning:

> If this attribute value is enclosed in quotation marks, the quotations must match.

Clearly, the quotations *do* match. The warning appears if I use single or double quotes.

For context, here is the surrounding code:

```
<span style="cursor: pointer;">
    <span class='fa-stack fa-lg @colorStyle' 
          data-toggle="tooltip" 
          data-placement="bottom" 
          title='@status'>
        <i class=' fa fa-circle-thin fa-stack-2x'></i>
        <i class="fa fa-database fa-stack-1x" 
           style="color: #ff4f4f;"></i>
    </span>
</span>
```

I did try ensuring that any attribute that included Razor variables was enclosed in single quotes, and that had no effect.

Can anyone explain why this is occurring, and how to fix it?

Comment: Stupid question, but I'll ask anyway: what happens if you remove the space at the beginning of the attribute value?

Comment: @Amy, Not a stupid question at all. In fact, if I remove it, the error goes away. Surprising, to say the least. Bug in the HTML validator? Even though the space is unnecessary, I would think a space does not necessarily mark the end of an attribute, especially since it starts with a quote.

Comment: Wow.  I guess I'll submit that as an answer, then.  I see nothing in the HTML5 spec that would disallow an attribute value from starting with a space, so I assume its a bug in the validator.

Comment: While the spec doesn't dictate that double quotes must be used around attribute values, that's certainly the convention, and Intellisense is convention-based. I would suggest using double quotes, rather than single, and that will probably fix the issue. It will also make me not hate you as much ;).

Comment: If anyone wants to submit a more complete answer than my own, please feel free.  I didn't expect the space at the start of the attribute to make much of a difference, and I don't need the rep.

Comment: @ChrisPratt, I originally used double-quotes. I changed it to single to see if it would fix the issue. It did not. Removing the leading space (within the quotes!) did.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the space from the start of the attribute.  It's valid per the HTML5 spec, but the VS validator is bugged.